# How many times does static int execute?

Tags: c++, static, int

```
void Test (int alpha)
{
    static int n = 0;
    n = n + alpha;
    cout << n << " ";
}
```

If I run Test (2); Test (4); Test (6); then the output should be 2 6 12. I don't understand why, I know that n will exist throughout the entire program because of the universal scope but I thought that static meant "unchangeable." Or in this case does it just mean that the line "static int n = 0;" will only execute once? Is this always the case?

Comment: You are confusing scope and storage class.

Answer (score 2):

`static` in a function scope means the variable is defined only once and it lives across all invocations of the function.

If you want to make it unchangeable, you have to make it `static const`

```
static const int n = 0;
```

If you do that, the line

```
n = n + alpha;
```

will produce a compiler error.

Answer (score 1):

No, it simply means that the line `static int n = 0;` will execute once, but it can be changed any number of times later on in the program.

Answer (score 0):

`static` does not mean "unchangeable"; that's what `const` means.  `static` refers to storage class.

Comment: What exactly does that mean though?

Comment: @user40467 It means that `n` behaves like a global variable (that is, it retains its value between function calls), but it is in-accesible outside your function.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that n will exist throughout the entire program because of the universal scope but I thought that static meant "unchangeable."

No. That's what `const` is for.

> Or in this case does it just mean that the line "static int n = 0;" will only execute once?

Yes.

> Is this always the case?

Rules are rules.